# stacking data in python

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a dataset as below stored as pandas data frame (df)

```
device_id  domain    date      event  product_label     event   Product_label1
   11      Amazon  24112017    basket                   view        TV
   12      Tesco   30122017    basket                   view        Coffe
   15      Costco  20092018    basket                   view        Clothes
```

I tried using the panda's stack function  df.stack() which doesn't render the right format

Below is the format I want to reshape the data as,

```
device_id  domain    date      event  product_label     
   11      Amazon  24112017    basket
   11      Amazon  24112017    view     TV   
   12      Tesco   30122017    basket
   12      Tesco   30122017    view     Coffe
```

Referred to the below stack-overflow as well doesn't work for the above problem 
[Python Pandas Wide to Long Format Change with Column Titles Spliting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643445/python-pandas-wide-to-long-format-change-with-column-titles-spliting)

Comment: Is the bottom an example of what you want or the output of `stack()`?

Comment: @Jaba, The output of stack() function is not attached, I have edited the question to make it clear, Thanks

Comment: Thanks, much easier to tell now. I'm not familiar with pandas but I can attempt to research it

Comment: May be best to have 2 tables imo as you're creating duplicate `device_id`'s and this seems like bad practice. I'd go with a `devices` dataframe and an `events` one. Just my 2 cents

Comment: I think that would just complex the code since the table I am trying to format is combined using multiple tables.

Comment: Use `df.melt(id_vars=['device_id','domain','date','Product_label1'], value_vars='event', value_name='event')`

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for [melt()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376053/pandas-dataframe-stack-multiple-column-values-into-single-column) question. Check to make sure I'm correct. I don't deal with pandas much.

```
df.melt(
    id_vars=['devide_id', 'domain'],
    value_vars=['event', 'product_label', 'product_label1']
)
```

Comment: Please let me know if I made a mistake I'll edit, or if I'm wrong I'll delete. Hope this helps!